# Customize Django login page

Tags: python, django

i'm using django.contrib.auth to auth. user. I'm using default login view, but i would like to add some more things (for example displaying number of already loge users). Is there any way to customize that view or i have to copy-paste it to my project and chage some things inside that? Is there are any way to call two views on one url?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, views are functions. You can write your own view that calls [Django's login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) at the end:

```
def mylogin(request):
    ...
    return login(request, 'my-login-template.html')
```

The kind of customization you want can happen in the template.

The default login view doesn't provide a way to extend the template's context, you'll have to use a context processor for that, or write your own view and calling the [login function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) instead, but that would mean writing more code which can introduce bugs.

Comment: Many thanks Gonzalo. It realy worked out! Just adding dictionary in extra_context and i can customize my template. Thanks alot. :)